# How to find derivative of improper integral with variable limit?

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, improper-integrals

I am working with the following, general improper integral and I need to compute it's derivative.
$$F(x)=\int_{x}^{\infty}f(s,t)^2ds$$

I want to say that derivative of integral is just the function, but the square is throwing me off. Is it just
$$\frac{d}{dx}(F(x))=\frac{d}{ds}F(s)=2f(s,t)f_x(s,t)?$$

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure it is $t$ and not $x$ inside the integral ?

Comment: $dF(x)=\int_{x+dx}^\infty f(s,t)^2\,ds-\int_{x}^\infty f(s,t)^2\,ds=$ $-\int_{x}^{x+dx} f(s,t)^2\,ds=$ $-f(x,t)^2\,dx$, $dF/dx=-f(x,t)^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Look up the [Leibniz integal rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule). In your case, it yields
$$ \frac{d}{dx}\left(\int_{x}^{\infty} f(s,t)^2 ds\right) = -f(x,t)^2.$$